# Is there a metric to compare BOW vs TFIDF results?

Tags: natural-language-processing, bag-of-words, tf-idf

I am working on a document search task and have used Bag of Words (BOW) and TFIDF vectorization techniques. My observation after going through some sample searches are -

- Both of them seem to provide similar results when we look at top X results for a given search term.
- However, in some cases BOW might give a slightly better top X results compared to TFIDF and vice versa.
- The cases in which TFIDF is slightly better is comparatively more than cases in which BOW is slightly better.

I wish to select either of the two and based on above eyeballing I decided to go with TFIDF. But this is not explainable since the decision is based on individual perspective after looking at some sample cases. I would like to know if there is some kind of metric that I can make use of to arrive at a decision? Since eyeballing can lead to biased decision.